# iOS: Settings w/ expandable list

Tags: iphone

Settings for Mail allows one to add items to a list (the list of accounts) by choosing the "Add Account..." entry at the bottom of the list; info gets entered on a separate screen, and now the list has a new entry.

Is there a way for someone other than Apple to accomplish this & still get into the App store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for someone other than Apple to accomplish this & still get into the App store?

No. There is no public API to do something like that.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question. He misunderstood it, it is indeed possible. (not to add e-mail accounts, but to add elements to a list the way you are asking for)

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking can someone modify the add new account list under mail settings programmatically, the answer is no.  Even if there was a private API I doubt it would get through the apple review.

Comment: No, I wanted to be able to do something similar w/in my own app, but it sounds like that's not possible, either.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this ancient thread, but just for completeness' sake: 

Of course it is possible to add rows to a UITableView in your app programatically during runtime. Or do you want to create an editable list inside the Settings app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a similar UI-functionality in your app as the one described.

Simply add a list element in the end of your TableView to act as a list footer with desired functionality.

Once clicked, swap to a another view. In this view you change the data source of your TableView so it contains a new element. Once you go back to the TableView, the new element can be drawn into the list.